# Yii2 - Implement Dark / Light Mode Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2, I use yii2-bootstrap4 for handle css UI: [Documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4)

My question is, how to implement SASS file to create switch button to change Day/Night Mode? I got this from internet: [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/bV4XYd7H9h)

This is my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^2.0",
    },
```

I know that we can override those Asset Bundle of css/js.
in config/web.php

```
'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
            'appendTimestamp' => YII_ENV_DEV ? false : true,
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'js' => [
                        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'jquery.js' : 'jquery.min.js'
                    ]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => [
                        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/bootstrap.css' : 'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    ],
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js' => [
                        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/bootstrap.bundle.js' : 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
                    ]
                ],

            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark